# Impossible to bypass a session timeout in my company

Tags: java, http, kotlin, request, vert.x

I am coming to you to see if someone get my issue.
Let me explain the context:

We have a back side coded in Kotlin/Vertx and a front Side in Angular 8.
We upload and download some files on the datalake storage from Azure Cloud.
How we do that? An explorer is implemented in the front side and when we want to download a file, a request is sent to the back side and once it is finished we send a response success/error from back side to the front side.

Everything works well in local environement on upload or Download.
One particularity, In download side we can download ONE or SEVERAL files And when it is 2 or more files we compress them on back side before returning the response to the front side and download the 7zip file.

And as I said above, everything works well in our local environment.
But I am working on a big company and there some security as 4 minutes session TimesOut.

So when we have to download a file with a big size on my company environment even if it takes more than 4 minutes, it works because it hapenning something during the download (some packet are downloading).
[image]

But when we have to compress Big files, the time that the backside is zipping files (more than 4 minutes) the session cut (some firewall or something )

[image]

I tried to add a keep alive in front side or back side it doesn't worked.
I also tried every http code I found on the web but it its happening nothing.

Do you know how I can keep this session open by some function in Vertx?
Because, every thing I tried from vertx documentation or stackoverflow failed.

Thanks a lot for reading me,
Regards

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: There is no error the request is stopped that is all.